# Lambda in Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, lambda

I'd like to make a few labels in Tkinter in Python and i used this code. I want the text in every label to change when I click on it. I'm not quite sure how to do it. I have a list with the original text and a list with the text I want to show when the label is clicked. I don't know if I should call a method to change the text or if I can do it in the lambda; or if there's any other, better way to do it. I'm don't really know how to use the lambda function here. Please help. :D
Thanks

```
for rows, rowinlist enumerate(self.list):
            for columns, label_text in enumerate(rowinlist):
                self.label = ttk.Label(text = label_text)
                self.fraze_otazky_label.grid(row = rows, column = columns)
                self.fraze_otazky_label.bind("<Button>", lambda : )
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

please also read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define a function that does the work. I your case there doesn't appear to be any need to use `lambda`.

When a bound function is called, it is passed an object representing the event. One of the attributes of the object is a reference to the widget. You can use this information to know which label was clicked on.

Here is a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def change_label(event):
    event.widget.configure(text="I was clicked")

for row in range(10):
    for column in range(10):
        label = tk.Label(text="Hello, world", width=15, bd=1, relief="raised")
        label.grid(row=row, column=column)
        label.bind("<1>", change_label)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How to do it if there is for example 15 lables - 3 rows, in each row 5 labels?
list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]

Comment: @Daniel: I don't understand your question. Just change the values in the loops to be whatever you want.

Comment: How should I edit the 
 `
def change_label(event):
      event.widget.configure(text=...)

 ` So it would change with every label to another text?